# How to add a user parameter into a power query

Tags: powerquery

I am struggeling to add a user parameter into a power query.

My query code without the parameter looks like this:

```
 let
    Source = PostgreSQL.Database("host", "user", [Query="select * from analysis where as_of_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 day'"])
in
    Source
```

How can I remove the hardcode 3 with an additional user input parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table tParameters in your workbook, containing column "Days". 
In the 1st row enter your value.

This code can contain errors as I have no PostgreSQL server nearby. :)

Also, it may generate data privacy error. Then you just either switch data privacy off, or move the step "Days" into a separate query ***named "Days"*** and set data privacy level for both your database and current workbook.

```
 let
    Source = PostgreSQL.Database("host", "user"){[Schema = "dbo", Item = "analysis"]}[Data], 
    Days = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tParameters"]}[Content]{0}[Days],
    FilterRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [as_of_date] > DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) - Days) 

//if CURRENT_DATE is not a current date on local(!) system, but a field, then 
//    FilterRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [as_of_date] > [CURRENT_DATE] - Days) 
//Never use native queries unless there is absolutely no other way.

in
    FilterRows
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    let
            Source = (daysBack)=>PostgreSQL.Database("host", "user", [Query="select * from analysis where as_of_date > 
                                  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL ' " & Text.From(daysBack)& " day'"])
    in

            Source
```

I have looked at the specification for finding the proper syntax at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt299038.aspx

Comment: This answer works, but be aware you're at risk for SQL Injection attacks against your database if a bad guy is allowed to change `daysBack` to something evil. You could instead use [`Table.SelectRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260810.aspx) to wrie the same row filter in M.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.